# How to set up Firebase Crashlytics for Debug and Release mode

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, android-productflavors

I would like to set up crashlytics for debug and release mode but I can't find proper informations in firebase docs.

At now the app is in one project and there is only one crashlytics for debug and release. I can't create another app with the same package as a previous one.
Another option is to have another project with the same package as the first one but I need to have one project due to api keys and other functionalities.

I have some two ideas but without a solution:

1. One project -> two apps (with the same package? -> at now it doesn't work) -> two google-services.json and flavours.
2. One project -> one app -> two setup of crashlytics for debug and release (how to do that?)

Does anyone have some some tips which could help to solve this case?

Comment: Try creating a different app with different package name <your package>.debug . And use the debug app google-services.json inside src/debug folder.

Your app's build.gradle will look like this 
  --- debug { \n
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug" \n
            debuggable true} ---

Haven't tried it, and I don't have enough time for it. Please try and let know :)

Comment: @Slashbin It doesn't work because I can't have two package names in one android app.

Comment: But the accepted answer says the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both options are possible. However the first one would result in two separate *Firebase* projects, which is less managable. It's better to stick with one *Firebase* project and with the same app.

In short:

The package identifier should be different to make a difference between the debug and release variant in one project. We can distinct this by using the build type.

Next, the second identifier can be added to the *Firebase* project. *Crashlytics* will make the distinction between them in the app.

---

To achieve that, we can do the following.

### 1. In the *Firebase Console*

a. Go to the project settings.

b. Add an **additional** Android app with the following configuration:

- App identifier: `<app_identifier>.debug`
- Name: // (Anything), make sure to mark it with something like `Debug` at the end

c. Register this app

d. Download the `google-services.json` file, we will need it in the next step.

e. Go to the *Crashlytics* tab in the left menu

f. Enable *Crashlytics* for both the apps

- Press `Next` at the second step
- Ignore the third step, building the code will enable it

### 2. Android source

a. Place the `google-services.json` file in the project (under the `app` folder) -> Overwrite the old one

b. Open the `app/build.gradle` file.

- Inside the `android` block, the `buildTypes` will be shown.
- For the `debug` build type, add `applicationIdSuffix '.debug'` (add the debug type if it doesn't exist in the file)
- This will cause the debug build type, to have `.debug` after the actual package identifier for the debug build.
- Release builds will be unaffected by this

c. Result, it should look like this:

```
android {
    // ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
        release {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Done!

Make a crash and it will result in the corresponding app in *Firebase Crashlytics*. There is a dropdown with both the projects at the top-left of the page.

Now, *Crashlytics* will automatically use the right *Firebase* app when sending a crash report. This works, since the `google-services.json` actually contains the configuration for both the build types. *Crashlytics* will use the right one based on the package identifier.

*Last note:* Don't forget enable *Crashlytics* at the *Crashlytics* tab in the *Firebase Console* (as described in step **1f**)

Comment: With this additional identifier - it seems to work fine :)

Comment: What is about other firebase products like , push notification, is this strategy will also work there?

Comment: Yeah, the other products like push notifications will also work fine with this configuration. As the Firebase project has the same server key, push will work fine for both build types